# Using awk to search for a line that starts with but also contains a string

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file that has multiple lines that starts with a keyword. I only want to modify one of them and it's easy to distinguish the two. I want the one that is under the `[dbinfo]` section. The domain name is static so I know that won't change.

```
awk -F '=' '$1 ~ /^dbhost/ {print $NF};' myfile.txt
```

## myfile.txt

```
[ual]
path=/web/
dbhost=ez098sf

[dbinfo]
dbhost=ec0001.us-east-1.localdomain
dbname=ez098sf_default
dbpass=XXXXXX
```

Comment: so, what is the desired output?

Comment: I eventually want to modify the value for that parameter. So, I dont want to touch the `dbhost` value under `[ual]`, I want the one under `[dbinfo]`.

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match the question. The line doesn't contain the string, it's in a block that starts with some other string.

Comment: Will `sed` do? Try `sed '/^\[dbinfo]$/,/^\[/{s/dbhost=.*/dbhost=replacement/}'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this awk command to first check for presence of `[dbinfo]` section and then modify `dbhost` parameter:

```
awk -v h='newhost' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}
       $0 == "[dbinfo]" {sec=1} sec && $1 == "dbhost"{$2 = h; sec=0} 1' file

[ual]
path=/web/
dbhost=ez098sf

[dbinfo]
dbhost=newhost
dbname=ez098sf_default
dbpass=XXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to utilize a little bit of a state machine here:

```
awk -F '=' '
    $0 ~ /^\[.*\]/ {in_db_info=($0=="[dbinfo]"}
    $0 ~ /^dbhost/{if (in_db_info) print $2;}' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with sed:

```
sed '/\[dbinfo\]/,/\[/s/\(^dbhost=\).*/\1domain.com/' myfile.txt
```